# void* pass in C# through ref

Tags: c#, visual-c++, pointers, dll, dllimport

There is a function in vc++ dll.

```
void fun(unsigned int nchannel,int nFGHandle,void* i);
```

Now I want to call this dll in my c# code.
I am using like this,

```
[DllImport ("AVC.dll")]
public static extern void fun(UInt32 a,int b,ref void c );
```

So I want to ask

1. Is there any need of marshling?
2. how to use ref for **void* i** in c#

Comment: is `unsigned int` really `UInt32`? I thought `int` depends on the platform (32 vs. 64 bit)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx. Would have to mark the method as unsafe however..  I'm sure there is a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you use `IntPtr` to marshal `void *`, however, if you need the return value, you can directly use `out <type>` and have several overloads, e.g.:

```
[DllImport ("AVC.dll")]
public static extern void fun(UInt32 a,int b, out int c );
[DllImport ("AVC.dll")]
public static extern void fun(UInt32 a,int b, out float c );
```

etc.